# Detecting nuclear DNA in suspension of mitochondria

Tags: biochemistry, mitochondria, dna-isolation

Is there a way to detect nuclear DNA in a suspension of mitochondria extracted from leukocytes? I need to make sure there is no nuclear DNA in the suspension before extracting mtDNA from the mitochondria.

Answer (score 3):

Centrifuge the suspension in Cesium Chloride solution at a particular g value which causes the mitochondria to settle to the bottom of the centrifuge tube but leaves nuclear DNA forming a layer near the top of the centrifuge tube. This is since the nuclear DNA is less dense than the mitochondria. Using a needle syringe, extract a small part of the centrifuged suspension from the very bottom of the centrifuge tube. This extract is most likely to contain no nuclear DNA. Hope this helps :).